# Error when trying to get data from json response url via php

Tags: php, json

I am using the code below to get some data from the json response using the url provided. This is mainly to get lat long from given coordinates for a site I am creating. I am not sure why I am getting

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

error but I may have made a mistake as I have not used JSON before

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/cm20re?callback=foo');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result
```

Now I get this echoed on the screen

```
/**/ typeof foo === 'function' && foo({"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"CM2 0RE","quality":1,"eastings":570635,"northings":206427,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"East of England","longitude":0.469458924538463,"latitude":51.7305869996012,"parliamentary_constituency":"Chelmsford","european_electoral_region":"Eastern","primary_care_trust":"Mid Essex","region":"East of England","lsoa":"Chelmsford 010D","msoa":"Chelmsford 010","incode":"0RE","outcode":"CM2","admin_district":"Chelmsford","parish":"Chelmsford, unparished area","admin_county":"Essex","admin_ward":"Moulsham and Central","ccg":"NHS Mid Essex","nuts":"Heart of Essex","codes":{"admin_district":"E07000070","admin_county":"E10000012","admin_ward":"E05004107","parish":"E43000062","ccg":"E38000106","nuts":"UKH36"}}});
```

Not sure how to pick a specific value

here is the print value

```
stdClass Object ( [status] => 200 [result] => stdClass Object ( [postcode] => CM2 0RE [quality] => 1 [eastings] => 570635 [northings] => 206427 [country] => England [nhs_ha] => East of England [longitude] => 0.46945892453846 [latitude] => 51.730586999601 [parliamentary_constituency] => Chelmsford [european_electoral_region] => Eastern [primary_care_trust] => Mid Essex [region] => East of England [lsoa] => Chelmsford 010D [msoa] => Chelmsford 010 [incode] => 0RE [outcode] => CM2 [admin_district] => Chelmsford [parish] => Chelmsford, unparished area [admin_county] => Essex [admin_ward] => Moulsham and Central [ccg] => NHS Mid Essex [nuts] => Heart of Essex [codes] => stdClass Object ( [admin_district] => E07000070 [admin_county] => E10000012 [admin_ward] => E05004107 [parish] => E43000062 [ccg] => E38000106 [nuts] => UKH36 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch data from your `json_decode` function instead your `curl` result

So change

```
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result->eastings;// You need to fetch it form $obj instead of $result
```

To

```
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->eastings;// use $obj
```

Updated

You can get your value using

```
$obj->result->eastings
```

Comment: echo `$result` and post it's value!! OR `print_r($obj)` and post its value!!

Comment: Okay that has echoed the whole json response, no how do I select a particular part?

Comment: aslo post `print_r($obj)` value!!'

Comment: I get nothing when I do that

Comment: remove `typeof foo === 'function' && foo(` part from string and make a valid json file

Comment: I have added that to the question, see above

Comment: Use `$obj->result->eastings`

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array is the error I now get